# Create a scrollbar to a full window tkinter in python

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a `tkinker` window with several buttons and layouts that use place. I tried to create a scrollbar to the entire window, but I can not place the button in the frame. Can someone help me, how can I add this button on the frame?

```py
#btn1 = tk.Button(win,
                  text="Browse...",
                  compound="left",
                  fg="blue", width=22,
                  font=("bold", 10),
                  height=1,
                  )

#btn1.place(x=600, y=0)
import json
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog as fd

win = Tk()
win.geometry("500x500")

# main
main_frame = Frame(win)
main_frame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

# canvas
my_canvas = Canvas(main_frame)
my_canvas.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=1)

# scrollbar
my_scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(main_frame, orient=VERTICAL, command=my_canvas.yview)
my_scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

# configure the canvas
my_canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=my_scrollbar.set)
my_canvas.bind(
    '<Configure>', lambda e: my_canvas.configure(scrollregion=my_canvas.bbox("all"))
)

second_frame = Frame(my_canvas)

my_canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=second_frame, anchor="nw")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Creating a Scrollable Frame:

If you want to make a frame (say `target_frame`) scrollable, you must follow the below 5 steps:

1. Create a frame (say `outer_frame`) to serve as a parent for a canvas and the scrollbar.
2. Add `target_frame` as an item to the canvas using the `.create_window()` method.
3. Connect the canvas and scrollbar with each other using `command = canvas.yview` and `yscrollcommand = scrollbar.set` in the appropriate places.
4. Specify which region of the canvas should be scrollable. If you want the entire canvas to be scrollable, use `canvas.configure(scrollregion = canvas.bbox("all")`.
5. Add all the required widgets to `target_frame`, not to the `outer_frame` or the canvas.

[image]

---

### Solution:

Broadly, your code has the following 3 problems:

1. You have not given `win.mainloop()` without which your tkinter application will not open.
2. The parent of `btn1` should be `second_frame`, not `win`.
3. `second_frame` has not been initialised with a `width` and `height`. Whenever a frame is added to a canvas using the `.create_window()` method, it must have a predefined `width` and `height`. Otherwise, the frame will not be displayed.

Also, remember that to get the vertical scrollbar working, the `height` of `second_frame` should be greater than the `height` of `my_canvas`.

In your code, `target_frame` and `outer_frame` correspond to `second_frame` and  `main_frame` respectively. I made the above 3 changes to your code to get it working.

**Working Code:**

```
import json
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog as fd

win = Tk()
win.geometry("500x500")

# main
main_frame = Frame(win)
main_frame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

# canvas
my_canvas = Canvas(main_frame)
my_canvas.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=1)

# scrollbar
my_scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(main_frame, orient=VERTICAL, command=my_canvas.yview)
my_scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

# configure the canvas
my_canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=my_scrollbar.set)
my_canvas.bind(
    '<Configure>', lambda e: my_canvas.configure(scrollregion=my_canvas.bbox("all"))
)

second_frame = Frame(my_canvas, width = 1000, height = 100)
btn1 = tk.Button(second_frame,
                  text="Browse...",
                  compound="left",
                  fg="blue", width=22,
                  font=("bold", 10),
                  height=1,
                  )

btn1.place(x=600, y=0)

my_canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=second_frame, anchor="nw")
win.mainloop()
```

Comment: I needed to add "my_canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=second_frame, anchor="nw")" to get this to work.

Answer (score 2):

For starters I would recommend removing your redundant import statement. I would use import tkinter as tk for readability, it's always nice to know what module your code is calling functions & methods from. It look like you set your window size and place your button outside that. I adjusted your x and y position.  The example below will put the button on your screen.

```
import json
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog as fd


win = tk.Tk()
win.geometry("500x500")

# main
main_frame = tk.Frame(win)
main_frame.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

# canvas
my_canvas = tk.Canvas(main_frame)
my_canvas.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

# scrollbar
my_scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(main_frame, orient=tk.VERTICAL, command=my_canvas.yview)
my_scrollbar.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)

btn1 = tk.Button(main_frame,
                  text="Browse...",
                  compound="left",
                  fg="blue", width=22,
                  font=("bold", 10),
                  height=1,
                  )

btn1.place(x=300, y=300)

# configure the canvas
my_canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=my_scrollbar.set)
my_canvas.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: my_canvas.configure(scrollregion=my_canvas.bbox("all")))

second_frame = tk.Frame(my_canvas)

my_canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=second_frame, anchor="nw")
```