# problems adding a scrollbar to a canvas in tkinter

Tags: tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I have been following many tutorials on how to add a scroll bar to a canvas, however, I've run into a number of problems that I am not able to solve. at first, I tried directly adding a scrollbar to the canvas however the scrollbar would be greyed out as shown below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KfHvg.png

and the relevant code:

```
def student_menu():
    csr = db.cursor()
    student_window = tk.Toplevel(root)
    student_window.title("Student Menu")
    student_window.geometry("700x500")

    label = tk.Label(student_window, text = "Welcome to the student menu")
    label.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 2)

    canvas = tk.Canvas(student_window, width = 700, height = 500)
    canvas.grid(row = 1, column = 0, columnspan = 2)
    scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(student_window, orient = "vertical", command = 
    canvas.yview)
    scrollbar.grid(row = 1, column = 2, sticky = "ns")
    canvas.configure(yscrollcommand = scrollbar.set)

    csr.execute("USE miniia")
    csr.execute("SELECT * FROM students")
    data = csr.fetchall()
    i = 0
    for row in data:
        for j in range(len(row)):
            e = tk.Entry(canvas, width = 20)
            e.grid(row = i + 1, column = j)
            e.insert(0, row[j])
        i += 1
    csr.close()
```

my second attempt tried to embed a frame in the canvas with the relevant table and then embed the table of entry widgets in it to scroll that. however, a strange grey box appeared over the table which otherwise has a correct scroll wheel and functionality shown below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VaZGI.png

relevant code:

```
def student_menu():
    csr = db.cursor()
    student_window = tk.Toplevel(root)
    student_window.title("Student Menu")
    student_window.geometry("700x500")

    label = tk.Label(student_window, text = "Welcome to the student menu")
    label.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 2)

    frame = tk.Frame(student_window)
    frame.grid(row = 1, column = 0, columnspan = 2)

    csr.execute("USE miniia")
    csr.execute("SELECT * FROM students")
    data = csr.fetchall()
    i = 0
    for row in data:
        for j in range(len(row)):
            e = tk.Entry(frame, width = 20)
            e.grid(row = i + 1, column = j)
            e.insert(0, row[j])
        i += 1
    csr.close()
    
    canvas = tk.Canvas(student_window, width = 700, height = 500)
    canvas.grid(row = 1, column = 0, columnspan = 2)
    canvas.create_window(0, 0, anchor = 'nw', window = frame)
    frame.update_idletasks()
    canvas.config(scrollregion = canvas.bbox('all'))
    scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(student_window, orient = 'vertical', command = 
    canvas.yview)
    scrollbar.grid(row = 1, column = 3, sticky = 'ns')
    canvas.config(yscrollcommand = scrollbar.set)
```

I have no idea how to continue from here.

Comment: I think you made a mistake while formatting your code. The indentation is not correct. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71796132/edit) your question and fix the indentation.

Comment: In your second approach, change `frame = tk.Frame(student_window)` to `frame = tk.Frame(canvas)` because `frame` has to be a child of `canvas`. (Don't forget to define `canvas` before creating `frame`.) Your first approach doesn't work because you can scroll only those widgets in the canvas which have been added as an item using the `.create_...()` method. Refer to [this](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/canvas.html) for more information about canvas items.

Comment: If you want to understand how exactly the above change makes the canvas scrollable, you can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71677889/create-a-scrollbar-to-a-full-window-tkinter-in-python/71682458#71682458).

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I managed to get it to work with your suggestions.